# How do I get MessageBox icon using WinAPI

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, messagebox

I have a   WH_CALLWNDPROC   hook code which handles   WM_INITDIALOG   message to get information about message boxes. I could get "Message", "Title", "Buttons" but I couldnt get "icon" information. I'm trying to use a function like below:

```
long getIcon(HWND hwnd) { // handle of messagebox dialog
    HWND hlbl = GetDlgItem(hwnd,20);

    wcout << "LABEL HWND: " << hlbl << endl;

    if (hlbl != NULL) { 
         LRESULT r =  SendMessage(hlbl,WM_GETICON,0,0);
         return (long)r; 
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

function always returns 0. I have checked by MS Spy++ and I saw that icon handle is 0. 
What is the correct way to get icon?

Comment: The `MessageBox` icons are system icons that you can load via `LoadImage` (or `LoadIcon`) with `IDI_INFORMATION`, `IDI_ERROR`, `IDI_WARNING`, or `IDI_QUESTION`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon that is displayed on the message box dialog is implemented using a [`STATIC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760769.aspx) control with `SS_ICON` style. You can obtain the icon handle by sending that control the [`STM_GETICON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760775.aspx) message.

In the code in your question, the variable named `hlbl` is actually the window handle of the `STATIC` control that contains the icon. I'd name it `hIconWnd`. With that name change, the code to obtain the icon would look like this:

```
HICON getIcon(HWND hwnd) { // handle of messagebox dialog
    HWND hIconWnd = GetDlgItem(hwnd, 20);
    if (hIconWnd != NULL) { 
         return (HICON)SendMessage(hIconWnd, STM_GETICON, 0, 0); 
    }
    return NULL; 
}
```